# Peut-on utiliser couramment "d'ores et déjà" ?

Tags: expressions, usage, locutions

> Je t'invite d'ores et déjà à bien noter ce créneau.

Peut-on utiliser couramment la locution adverbiale "d'ores et déjà" pour dire dès maintenant ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, l'expression est tout à fait utilisable et utilisée aujourd'hui, y compris comme dans la phrase proposée dans la question où ***d'ores et déjà*** insiste sur l'immédiateté de l'invitation, ce qui se comprend en analysant la signification originale de chacun de ses composant :

*D'ores*  : à partir de maintenant
*Déjà*      : c'est fait

Un [exemple d'utilisation](https://www.culture.gouv.fr/Presse/Archives-Presse/Archives-Discours-2012-2018/Annee-2017/Discours-de-Francoise-Nyssen-prononce-au-Congres-de-l-Association-des-Bibliothecaires-de-France) :

> *Je vous invite d’ores et déjà à en retenir la date : elle aura lieu le samedi 20 janvier 2018.* Françoise Nyssen, Ministre de la culture, 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Selon le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9O0609) :

> 2. Adv. Dans la langue classique, s’employait familièrement pour interpeller, pour inviter, pour exhorter. *Or ça, Monsieur. Or sus, commençons !*

> ▪  Anciennement. *Or* ou ses variantes *ore* ou *ores* se disaient pour *Maintenant.* *Ores* ne s’emploie plus aujourd’hui que dans la locution adverbiale *d’ores et déjà*, dès maintenant, désormais.

> *L’affaire est d’ores et déjà réglée.* <==> *L’affaire est désormais réglée.*

Answer (score 2):

J'aimerais nuancer la réponse de TUI lover : selon moi, on peut très bien avoir "*dès maintenant*" comme un des sens de "*d'ores et déjà*", mais dans le sens de "*à partir de maintenant*".

Je ne sais pas si c'est le français le plus correct, mais à l'oral c'est une locution que j'ai souvent entendu de la part de professeurs ou de l'administration durant mes études, et ça ne m'a jamais choqué.

> Vous pouvez d'ores et déjà télécharger l'emploi du temps des examens sur le site de l'université

Dans cette phrase je ne dirais pas que l'action est déjà effectuée, mais plutôt qu'il est possible de l'effectuer, et ce *dès maintenant*. L'emploi avec "*vous pouvez*" a l'air relativement [courant](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/vous+pouvez+d%27ores+et+d%C3%A9j%C3%A0.html).

Dans l'exemple de ta question par contre, l'emploi n'est pas approprié. *Dès maintenant* y a un sens d'urgence, de "*sans tarder*", "*au plus tôt*". C'est assez différent de "*dès maintenant*" dans le sens "*à partir de maintenant*", "*à compter d'aujourd'hui*".

---

On peut noter aussi qu'il y a d'autres problème dans la construction de ta phrase :

> Je t'invite d'ores et déjà à noter ce créneau

Ici, *d'ores et déjà* s'applique à "*je t'invite*", ce qui n'a pas vraiment de sens puisque l'invitation est faite dans la phrase. Il faudrait plutôt dire :

> Je t'invite à d'ores et déjà noter ce créneau

Dans cette phrase, c'est bien à "*noter ce créneau*" que s'applique "*d'ores et déjà*".

Même comme ça, ça reste une locution un peu lourde pour simplement "*noter un créneau*", j'utiliserais plutôt "*dès maintenant*" ou "*tout de suite*".

Answer (score 1):

Non, *d’ores et déjà* indique que l’action a déjà été effectuée. En anglais, cela revient à utiliser le temps du parfait. Dès maintenant, en revanche, indique véritablement l’immédiateté.

Exemple :

- Le formulaire a d’ores et déjà été rempli. -> plus besoin de le remplir
- Le formulaire doit être rempli dès maintenant. -> il est encore à remplir

Comment: Non, *d'ores et déjà* n'implique pas que l'action a déjà été effectuée. Elle insiste au contraire sur l'immédiateté de cette dernière alors que *dès maintenant* est plus tourné vers le futur. D'autre part, l'action ici est l'invitation.

Comment: Même si « d’ores et déjà indique que *l’action* a déjà été effectuée » : — « Les formulaires étant  *d’ores et déjà* édités, vous pouvez [effectuer *l'action* de] les remplir » peut aussi s'écrire — « Les formulaires étant édités, vous pouvez *d’ores et déjà* [effectuer *l'action* de] les remplir » … que l'on se réfère aux formulaires ou à leur remplissage, *d’ores et déjà* rend les choses possibles, vous n'êtes pas obligé d'attendre plus longtemps/que l'on vous en donne l'ordre.